# Microsoft SQL INSERT INTO SELECT statement will select the correct data, but will not insert into data

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-insert

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table3 (column1, column2, column3)
    SELECT dbo.table1.value1, dbo.table1.value2, dbo.table2.value3 
    FROM dbo.table1 
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 ON dbo.table1.value1 = dbo.table2.value1  
    WHERE dbo.table2.date >= '2022-10-1 00:00:00'
```

Running the select statement by itself does select the correct data. Running the whole statement doesn't insert into the table. I get no errors, just "Commands Completed Successfully". I can insert values into the table directly, just not with the select statement.

The datatypes match between the values and the columns.

Does anyone have any idea what isn't working. My coworker and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please share sample data

Comment: Did you happen to issue a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement before this attempt? Or did you toggle ANSI mode on by accident? Tools -> Options -> Query Execution -> SQL Server -> ANSI

Comment: insert may start an implicit transaction, depending on your settings. execute a commit statement afterwards to commit that transaction. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: commiting the transaction didnt help, flipping ansi on/off didnt help either. i found a permission setting i had to toggle. thanks everyone!

Comment: First of all, even if the `SELECT` does what you want, I recommend using a "safe" date/time literal format (`20221001` or `2022-10-01T00:00:00`, per [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe)). Second, check for things like a trigger on the destination table, and double check your assumptions about what is and isn't happening in the table through a simple `COUNT(*)`. If all else fails try opening a new connection in case options where incorrectly set on the current one.

Comment: @Jeroen oh yes, thats actually going to be a variable "today's date" in the final product. i just had a hardcoded literal to check that it works/actual brings in data. Sorry about that and thanks!